# What library can I use to implement this chart in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

apologies if the question is not phrased the best way but I'm not a native English speaker and I'm not sure how this chart is called exactly. Basically this is what I'm looking for :

[image]

Do you know a library that I can use to implement this chart and if you could point me to an example I'd be very grateful!

Comment: You look like needing search engine (Google)

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I've tried with Google thing is I can't figure out how to have multiple columns/bars per section which are not grouped together - pretty much every library I found offered just a basic column chart which wouldn't work in my case - which is why I thought someone here might have dealt with this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chartjs` [visit chartsJs official site.](http://www.chartjs.org/)  You are talking about a vertical bar cart. See chartjs documentation for the modifications you like to make. If you want to make groupings then chartsJs allows you to make groups, [See the example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgFJl.png) You can also make stacks and do many cool things like animations and so on.

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html

Comment: What do you mean by multiple columns per section?

Comment: well as you see in the picture for each year (Year 1, Year 2..) there are multiple columns however there's no space between them , that's what I want to accomplish

Comment: Answer is updated, see the image.

Answer (score 0):

you might like:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

if you want more options, you can also check how to make a bar chart with d3:
https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Comment: I've seen chartjs but I need to have multiple columns/bars per section which are not grouped together , as shown in the picture - this is what I can't figure out how to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/). It supports nice and easy customizations.